# NLTK Brown Corpus - adding own tagged sentences

Tags: python-2.7, nltk

I am trying to add a file with tagged sentences (that the Brown Corpus can read).
What I did is that I went to `nltk_data/corpora/brown`, added the file `tagged5` and went to `cats.txt` and added a line `tagged5 homework`.

But when I do:

```
brown_homework = brown.tagged_sents(categories='homework')
```

It just gives me `ValueError: "In category mapping file cats.txt: tagged5 not found"`

Although the file `tagged5` is there with all the other corpus files.

Any idea?

Comment: What is the content in `tagged5`?

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this, but munging the Brown corpus is a terrible hack. If you simply want to access your files using the Brown corpus reader, initialize a fresh `CategorizedTaggedCorpusReader` with just your data. If you have a different goal, explain and there's probably a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try to inject a file into the `nltk_data/corpora/brown` directory:

```
alvas@ubi:~/nltk_data/corpora/brown$ echo "This/DT is/VB a/DT foobar/JJ sentence/NN ./." > testfile
alvas@ubi:~/nltk_data/corpora/brown$ echo "testfile homework">>cats.txt
alvas@ubi:~/nltk_data/corpora/brown$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> "testfile" in brown.fileids()
False
```

Seems like injecting the file directly into the directory doesn't work. But reading the file works:

```
>>> brown.raw('testfile')
u'This/DT is/VB a/DT foobar/JJ sentence/NN ./.\n'
>>> brown.tagged_sents('testfile')
[[(u'This', u'DT'), (u'is', u'VB'), (u'a', u'DT'), (u'foobar', u'JJ'), (u'sentence', u'NN'), (u'.', u'.')]]
```

However you are still unable to access it from the `brown.categories()` or the `fileids()`:

```
>>> brown.categories()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/api.py", line 326, in categories
    self._init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/nltk/corpus/reader/api.py", line 312, in _init
    'not found' % (self._file, file_id))
ValueError: In category mapping file cats.txt: testfile not found
```

First let's locate how Brown corpus is loaded in NLTK, see [https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/**init**.py#L74](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/develop/nltk/corpus/__init__.py#L74)

```
brown = LazyCorpusLoader(
    'brown', CategorizedTaggedCorpusReader, r'c[a-z]\d\d',
    cat_file='cats.txt', tagset='brown', encoding="ascii")
```

Now let's take a look at LazyCorpusLoader(), see http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/corpus/util.html#LazyCorpusLoader

Note the `r'c[a-z]\d\d'` argument when initializing the LazyCorpusLoader. It looks there is a specific naming convention to the brown corpus.

It has to start with a `c` and proceeds with a character from `[a-z]` and then followed by 2 digits. So let's use the filename `cz07` instead of `testfile`. (There is no cz07 in the original Brown corpus so it's okay).

So let's now remove the `testfile` and the last line that we've added in the `cats.txt`:

```
alvas@ubi:~/nltk_data/corpora/brown$ rm testfile
alvas@ubi:~/nltk_data/corpora/brown$ sed -i '$d' cats.txt 
alvas@ubi:~/nltk_data/corpora/brown$ ls cz07
ls: cannot access cz07: No such file or directory
alvas@ubi:~/nltk_data/corpora/brown$ echo "This/DT is/VB a/DT foobar/JJ sentence/NN ./." > cz07
alvas@ubi:~/nltk_data/corpora/brown$ echo "cz07 homework" >>cats.txt
alvas@ubi:~/nltk_data/corpora/brown$ python

>>> from nltk.corpus import brown
>>> 'cz07' in brown.fileids()
True
>>> 'homework' in brown.categories()
True
>>> brown.tagged_sents(categories='homework')
[[(u'This', u'DT'), (u'is', u'VB'), (u'a', u'DT'), (u'foobar', u'JJ'), (u'sentence', u'NN'), (u'.', u'.')]]
```

Voila!

Remember to remove the extra file you've added:

```
>> exit()
alvas@ubi:~/nltk_data/corpora/brown$ sed -i '$d' cats.txt
alvas@ubi:~/nltk_data/corpora/brown$ rm cz07
```